# How to extract Opportunity Name from formula naming convention?

Tags: formula

We have automation where when Opportunity record is created, it display Opportunity Name in following format:

Useralias - AccountName - OpportunityName - OpportunityAutoNumber

this formula has an issue when we clone the record. During record clone, it consider above complete name as a name and after clone it displays repeated string which I want to avoid.

I want to find out "OpportunityName" from the above string and then recreate the same formula as mentioned above in order to avoid duplicate value.

Let's say If I create hidden formula field where I want to extract OpportunityName from the above string, How can I acheieve the same?

Can someone please help how to do it?

Comment: Hi. You will have to provide more information in order for anyone to help you. What does you automation consist of? Apex trigger? Flow? Workflow rules? Formula fields? Please include the literal values or screenshots of that automation.

Comment: We have a Lightning flows which contains flow formula field that we are assigning it to Opportunity name.

Comment: If you can provide sample formula which can extract OpportunityName from those string, it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to backwards-engineer and extra the Opportunity Name from the concatenated value, I'd suggest storing the original Opportunity Name in a separate field (e.g. 'Original Opportunity Name') before concatenating those fields. The use the Original Opportunity Name for generating the Opportunity Name.

Then upon cloning, the Original Opportunity Name is also cloned and is used for the new Opportunity's name.

Comment: I have to store OpportunityName in a custom field and use before handler to do that and will have to bypass the automation while cloning the record. After that this is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I am considering that you are storing this name convention in Opportunity Name field and If you want to create hidden formula field that should capture OpportunityName then below formula might help:

```
SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(
RIGHT(
    Name,
    LEN(Name) - FIND(" - ", Name, FIND(" - ", Name) + FIND(" - ", Name) + FIND(" - ", Name))
),
OpportunityAutoNumber,''
),
'-',''
)
```

Replace OpportunityAutoNumber with your fieldapi name that stores autonumber.